# Why var hasn't capital letter (Var) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering something that may look stupid but C# has a definition for every type with capitalized letter :

`int -> Int32 , 
 double -> Double , 
 string -> String , 
 etc..`

Why does `var` isn't defined **Var** like other .Net component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Double` is the class name while `double` is an alias of the class. `var` is usually used in anonymous type. There is no class of `Var` unless you'll make one for it.

Comment: `float` -> `Single`? The convention you're imagining simply doesn't exist - *and* `var` isn't a type.

Comment: Pressing shift costs time, that's the reason why `var` is lowercase.

Comment: Why is this on hold as "opinion based"? It seems to be a legitimate question regarding class names and aliasing in C#.

Comment: var is just a c# compile-time gimmick, it has no meaning in CLR. c# compiler translates var to actual type. If you are curious, use some reflector to peek inside the generated assembly and see what gets replaced for var.

Comment: Disappointed to see this downvoted and put on hold.

Comment: I'm disappointed too,It looks like my question was too dumb or something like that. I will never ask a question like that again on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is a keyword with no mappable Primitive type. `int`, `double`, etc are all keywords with primitive mappings.

From msdn:

```
int i = 123;
```

> When an integer literal has no suffix, its type is the first of these
>   types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.
>   In this example, it is of the type int.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5kzh1b5w.aspx

`var` is special because the actual type that it represents is type inferred.

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two
>   declarations of i are functionally equivalent...

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet I stand corrected. I always thought string was a primitive. You're not allowed to play the string card. c# strings are an exception to every rule. :D

Comment: @Gusdor: It is not clear what "primitive" even means. The C# specification does not clearly define it. Best to simply avoid the term because any two people might mean something different by it.

Comment: @EricLippert I believe Mr Skeet (in his wisdom) was working off the results of the System.Type.IsPrimitive method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx I wasn't aware that it wasn't language defined. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

`int`, `double`, `string` and `var` are all [keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) and keywords are not capitalized, however `System.Int32`, `System.Double`, `System.String` are all Types and [Types are capitalized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx).

Comment: `System.Int32` and others are structures, not classes.

Comment: `var` is only a *contextual* keyword. It's not a "full" keyword, in that it's still a valid identifier. (So you can declare your own class called `var`. I wouldn't recommend it, but...)

Comment: @Habib: Correct for `Int32` and `Double` - but `String` is a class.

Comment: I changed my wording before the 5 minute mark, I used to say "classes" but I changed to to "types"